# wait and notify coordination

Tags: java, multithreading

There is a main thread that has a while loop, in this while he checks for some conditions and if all conditions are met he starts another threads enters wait() state.

Other threads that run in parallel notify the main thread upon work completion.

There is a problem when "sub thread" notifies the main thread **before** the main thread enters the wait state = dead lock.

What is the best practice to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the main thread doesn't wait for something that has already happened. (Why would anyone do that anyway? It makes no sense.)

Comment: +1: The javadoc for wait() explicitely explains that there should always be a loop checking for a condition to enter/exit from a wait state.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use Explicit [Locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html). See Java Concurrent Api.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a semaphore for the notification.

That's it, really.  A semaphore has a count and can record the notification until the main thread gets around to waiting on it.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is to use the concurrency package in Java 5. A CountDownLatch seems suitable here.

If you are limited to a pre Java 5 environment, you will have to create a custom implementation which uses the same algorithm. The main thread would call signalReady after creation of all child threads. The child threads would call signalComplete after completing their work.

A simple implementation would be to have an Object called a Latch with two two member fields.

> The below implementation will work for one parent and one child. For additional children, each child could be given its own latch to signal when complete. There would still be cases where this will be race conditions. Adding a spin lock or maybe a sleep between the signalling would reduce the probability of a race conditions. **It would not eliminate it**

```
class Latch{
  Object readyLock;
  Object completeLock;

  public void signalComplete(){
    synchronized(readyLock){
      readyLock.wait()
    }
    //spin lock as a precaution
    synchronized(completeLock){
      completeLock.notify()
    }
  }

  public void signalReady(){
    synchronized(readyLock){
      readyLock.notify()
    }
    synchronized(completeLock){
      completeLock.wait()
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This code is horribly broken and creates the very problem the OP is asking about! The `signalReady` function waits even if there is nothing to wait for. The `signalComplete` function does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very common practice to **almost always** put the `wait()` method in a `while` loop whose "iteration condition" is to check whether a particular event has occurred, on occurrence of which the other thread would have called the `notify()` method.

ex:

```
while(!event_occurrence) {
    ...
    wait();
    ...
}
```

where `event_occurrence` is the event on which the other thread would have called `notify()` method.

Comment: I don't think this will help cause: if there are 2 sub-threads. First sub-thread finishes=> event_occurrence=true, main thread enters the while loop. At this moment (before wait() is executed) sub-thread 2 finishes. then main thread executes wait() = > dead lock again

Comment: @markiz: Sub-thread 2 cannot finish except when this thread is in `wait` because this thread holds the lock. (It calls `wait` to release the lock as well as wait for the event.)

Comment: @David Schwartz, the lock in on the main thread. sub threads wake up the main thread. Main thread spawns the sub-threads and waits for any of them to finish. Then he does some logic and goes to sleep again.

Comment: @markiz: The important thing is that you follow this pattern: 1) Acquire the lock. 2) Check if there is something you need to wait for. If not, do whatever and then release the lock. 3) Wait, releasing the lock only while you're waiting. 4) Go to step 2. (The lock can be implicit in a `synchronized` block.)

Comment: @David Schwartz, thank you for your patience but I am still missing something. Main thread is waiting (no lock), sub-thread 1 completes and notifies -> main thread wakes-up->  Acquires the lock,in this moment sub_thread 2 completes its work and notifies... what now?

Comment: what I mean is how  the lock will prevent sub_threads from executing notify()? and how main thread can release lock while it waits?

Comment: @markiz: There's no problem in that case. The main thread has woken up, which is all that matters. The `wait` operation atomically releases the lock and blocks the thread (that's its purpose).

Comment: But in this case it will enter dead lock again: after  2) Check if there is something you need to wait=> returns "true"=>3)wait...
the sub_thread calls notify right between 2 and 3 => deadlock!!! (because there are no any other subthreads to notify) I need some how to prevent to notification between step 2 and 3

Comment: The sub thread can't call `notify` between 2 and 3. Until you call `wait`, you hold the lock. (It is `wait` that releases the lock.) It seems you still fundamentally don't understand the semantics of `wait`/`notify`. All state changes occur with the lock held. All tests of the state occur with the lock held. The lock protects the state.